# error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'

Tags: rtsp, yolov5, jetson-xavier

I'm trying to publish an RTSP Stream from a Jetson AGX Board using Intel RealSense Cameras and receive the stream on a remote device using Yolov5 (on the same VLAN).

[image]

RTSP server is running on the jetson board [Simple RTSP](https://github.com/aler9/rtsp-simple-server) **(IP Address:10.160.51.19)**:

> docker run --rm -it -e RTSP_PROTOCOLS=tcp -p 8554:8554 -p 1935:1935 -p 8888:8888 aler9/rtsp-simple-server

For publishing the Intel RealSense Camera stream on the RTSP Server, I used ffmpeg:

> ffmpeg -pix_fmt uyvy422 -i /dev/video6 -video_size 640x320 -f rtsp -framerate 90 rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream

For receiving the stream on the remote computer using yolov5 (on the same VLAN), I used to following:

> git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5.git

> cd yolov5

> pip install -r requirements.txt

> python detect.py --source rtsp://10.160.51.19:8554/mystream

I got the following error in yolov5:

> YOLOv5s summary: 213 layers, 7225885 parameters, 0 gradients                                                                                                                      [ERROR:0@93.109] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (166) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:                                                                                                                                                                                               OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): rtsp://10.160.51.19:8554/mystream in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                  File "C:\Users\5G\yolov5\detect.py", line 252, in                                                                                                main(opt)                                                                                                                                                                       File "C:\Users\5G\yolov5\detect.py", line 247, in main                                                                                                   run(**vars(opt))                                                                                                                                                                File "C:\Users\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\grad_mode.py", line 27, in decorate_context                                        return func(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                    File "C:\Users\5G\yolov5\detect.py", line 100, in run                                                                                                    dataset = LoadStreams(source, img_size=imgsz, stride=stride, auto=pt)                                                                                                           File "C:\Users\5G\yolov5\utils\datasets.py", line 328, in **init**                                                                                       assert cap.isOpened(), f'{st}Failed to open {s}'                                                                                                                              AssertionError: 1/1: rtsp://10.160.51.19:8554/mystream... Failed to open rtsp://10.160.51.19:8554/mystream

IMPORTANT NOTE:

Please note that when I publish the RTSP stream on other Linux machines (POP!_OS), the error doesn't occur and I'm able to receive the stream in Yolov5.

[image]

The above photo shows the stream can be viewed using Yolov5 locally(Linux) and remote (windows terminal) when the stream is published from Pop!_OS.
Even though both operating systems run on Debian Ubuntu, I'm getting the error in the Jetson AGX running Tegra, not Pop!_OS.

Thank you

Comment: Seems it is using wrong opencv capture backend (CV_IMAGES). 

You would rebuild it to specifically use gstreamer backend (such as cv::CAP_GSTREAMER in C++). 

This assumes your opencv build has gstreamer support, check with cv::getBuildInformation()